# Android menu items appear in a totally weird fashion

Tags: android, android-menu

I have a menu xml. Very basic and simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/item_bookmark"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_read"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_collab"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

However it appears like this:

[image: Items in weird fashion]

The first item appears fine. The second and onwards are getting "trimmed" or "cut" or whatever. `ifRoom`, `always`, `category` etc., nothing works. It appears like this in the preview itself. I am guessing I have enabled some setting in the style which is causing this.

Never thought I'll be stuck in an Android menu. Can anybody help me here?

My styles look like this (if someone wants to look at it)

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <!--<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/zifycolorDarker</item>-->

    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AllActivityWindowAnimationStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the answer!**

So I had accidentally used the wrong property for setting screen orientation. There is a property

```
<item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
```

This sets everything to portrait *even the components which need to be horizontal* .
Removed this and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this set up:

```
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_bookmark"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_read"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_collab"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I am sorry but no good. Thats what, I shouldn't even be asking about the menu here.  Just beats me.